# How to repeat calculation for every value in an array and store the vector of each result in a new array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

My calculation is performed for a pair of coordinates(x_mix, y_mix) (which is typed into the script), and the solution is stored in the 5x1 vector "C". So when the script is ran after typing in my coordinates into the script, I just type "C" in the command window to get my result.

I have a 130x2 matrix of 130 coordinates I want the calculation to be peformed on (called "xy_coordinates_of_black_body_curve"), so when the script is ran, I want each 5x1 Vector to be stored in a big array.

(Everything else is held constant, such as Y_mix, x_green etc)
(The matrix A is a 3x5 matrix, B is the pseudoinverse, C is the solution)

How can I do this?

```
 x_mix = 0.3
 y_mix = 0.4
 Y_mix = 40;
 A = [((x_amber - x_mix)/y_amber) ((x_green - x_mix)/y_green) ((x_blue - x_mix)/y_blue) ((x_white_2500K - x_mix)/y_white_2500K) ((x_white_6500K - x_mix)/y_white_6500K)

 ((y_amber - y_mix)/y_amber) ((y_green - y_mix)/y_green) ((y_blue - y_mix)/y_blue) ((y_white_2500K - y_mix)/y_white_2500K) ((y_white_6500K - y_mix)/y_white_6500K) 

 1 1 1 1 1];

B = pinv(A);

C = B*[0; 0; Y_mix];
```

Comment: So use [a loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html)...

Comment: Why not create a function? `function [out_array] = compute_c(in_array)
for i = 1:size(in_array,1)
A = [((x_amber - in_array(i, 1))/y_amber) ((x_green - in_array(i, 1))/y_green) ((x_blue - in_array(i, 1))/y_blue) ((x_white_2500K - in_array(i, 1))/y_white_2500K) ((x_white_6500K - in_array(i, 1))/y_white_6500K)
((y_amber - in_array(i, 2))/y_amber) ((y_green - in_array(i, 2))/y_green) ((y_blue - in_array(i, 2))/y_blue) ((y_white_2500K - in_array(i, 2))/y_white_2500K) ((y_white_6500K - in_array(i, 2))/y_white_6500K) 
1 1 1 1 1];
B = pinv(A);
out_array(:,i) = B*[0; 0; Y_mix];
end
end`

Comment: @RCaetano That code stings my eyes. Try to limit writing code in comments to a couple of lines or less.  Beyond that just looks fugly.

Comment: I would post as an answer to avoid that but it is marked as duplicate :/ And it is that ugly because intead of splitting across comments I was able to fit it with the maximum number of characters in a comment... It was just to help IgdI.y